# Import dlib on Jetson NX got Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: gpu, dlib, jetson-xavier

JetPack version: 4.6

I am trying to use dlib (GPU) on Jetson Xavier NX, following are my steps to install dlib

```
dowload repo: https://github.com/davisking/dlib
cd dlib-master
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1
cmake --build .
cd ..
sudo python3 setup.py install --set USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 --set DLIB_USE_CUDA=1
```

When I run import dlib

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jetpack 4.6. I had use a different version. Check your dlib version by typing

```
pip3 list
```

#I had dlib 19.22.0 and downgraded to 19.21.0

#Download the right package for face recoginition -http://dlib.net/files/
#Note you will need to install this package manually

```
wget http://dlib.net/files/dlib-19.XX.tar.bz2
tar jxvf dlib-19.XX.tar.bz2 #change XX accordingly
```

#Optional - search and comment out forward_algo = forward_best_algo;

```
/home/jn/dlib-19.XX/dlib/cuda
gedit cudnn_dlibapi.cpp
```

#cd .. to /dlib-19.XX to find setup.py #this will take a while to finish the installation

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
sudo pip3 install face_recognition
```